# How come git clean -Xi doesn't delete folders, only files?

Tags: git

My `.gitignore` has something like

```
/folder
/.otherFolder
.file
.otherFile
```

And when I do `git clean -Xi` it shows that it will only delete `.file` and `.otherFile`, but not `folder` or `otherFolder`.

Why is that?

EDIT: I'm running `git version 1.8.5.5`. Here's what `git help clean` looks like: http://hastebin.com/bilovusugi. The description for the -d option doesn't mention anything about gitignore. I want to remove only gitignored directories, but leave other untracked directories in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading `git help clean` I think you want to add the `-d` option.

I do not see a `-i` option.  Is that a typo or something added after version 1.7.10?

Comment: `-i` is for interactive. Please see my updated question. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Ah, cool! Thanks to benjifisher. So

```
git clean -Xi
```

doesn't delete folders because it does not include the `-d` option. The `-X` option combined with the `-d` option deletes folders that are both untracked AND gitignored.

So, use:

```
git clean -Xdi
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @BlueBerry-vignesh4303 How does it not? I've updated my answer to be more verbose. Plus, if you notice, I've marked his answer as the accepted answer so he got all the credit.

Comment: morning i have reviewed this post before the edit that made me to comment :) have a good day